# Date format in RangeValidator

Tags: asp.net, datetime, format, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using RangeValidator to validate date enter in textbox and its working fine with default date format but now i want the date format in "dd/MM/yyy" but its generating excption with this date format. please provide me solution
my code:

in aspx page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtrequiredby" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox >
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtrequiredby_CalendarExtender" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtrequiredby" >
</cc1:CalendarExtender >

 <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvreqby" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required By Date
Greater Than or Equal to current date" ControlToValidate="txtrequiredby" 
 Display="Dynamic" Type="Date" ></asp:RangeValidator >
```

in codebehind:

```
rvreqby.MinimumValue = clsGeneral.FromSqlDate( DateTime.Now);
rvreqby.MaximumValue = clsGeneral.FromSqlDate( DateTime.Now.AddYears(200));

public static string  FromSqlDate(DateTime  date)
{
   return date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MinimumValue & MaximumValue need to be set in the Page_PreRender event and appear to require the date format as "dd-MM-yy"...see last post on [Rangevalidator Min Max Value error](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303019.aspx)

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
    RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(90).ToString("dd-MM-yy");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Format of the MinimumValue and MaximumValue should be yyyy/MM/dd

Check documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydez7ad7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: for the application that I am writing I want the date format to be `MM/dd/yyyy` so it should be whatever it needs to be for your application.  And your link is broken

Comment: @Malachi: No. the MinimimValue should always be in format yyyy/MM/dd. The validator uses that format to validate. It's independent of culture.

Comment: Where does it say that? the article that you linked to says nothing about Date ranges.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1343117.aspx?Date+format+for+RangeValidator the accepted answer says that the date format is taken from the machine the code is housed on. and it also gives @MikeM's answer of how to resolve the situation to another format

Comment: in the MSDN it states: "If you specify ValidationDataType.Date for the BaseCompareValidator.Type property without programmatically setting the culture for the application, you should use a culture-neutral format, such as YYYY/MM/DD, for the MaximumValue and MinimumValue properties. Otherwise, the date may not be interpreted correctly."

So only when no culture is defined. However I had same problem as in question. Application culture was nl-NL, daterange date format was NL, did not work. Using the culture-neutral format YYYY/MM/DD fixed the problem.

Comment: I guess if it is on the back end it doesn't really matter if it doesn't match the user's expected format.

Comment: the format should match the backend (server side) culture. If that does not work use YYYY/MM/DD.