# ASP.Net C# and JavaScript textfield expiration date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am looking for a textbox that a user can enter an expiration date for his/her license. The user can only enter an expiration date that is between today's date and up to 12/31/2099.

This is what I have now:

```
function RangeValidation(dt)
        {
            var startrange = new Date(Date.parse("12/02/1900"));
            var endrange = new Date(Date.parse("12/31/2099"));
            var lblmesg = document.getElementById("<%=lblMesg.ClientID%>") ;
            if (dt<startrange || dt>endrange)
            {
                lblmesg.style.color="red";
                lblmesg.innerHTML = "Date should be between 12/01/2014 and 12/31/2099";
            }
        }

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRange" runat="server" MaxLength = "10" onkeyup = "ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" onkeydown = "return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is there an easier way to do that? I am running into date issues, for exampele dd/mm/yyyy and so on, I would like something simple in ASP.Net (I don't prefer using JavaScript cause I am not familiar with it)

Thanks.

Comment: How about using a datepicker or RangeValidator ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use asp.net RangeValidator, if that fits your requirement. Following links may help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.maximumvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

[Date format in RangeValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332600/date-format-in-rangevalidator)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1303019.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript. I strongly suggest using a `readonly` textbox with a popup date selector. Most of these selectors have range limits as you want. This is the ideal way of doing it. I can provide examples if you need.

You can check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/w6jf1eh0/).