# Cannot update asp:RangeValidator contained in ListView EditItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am struggling to get an asp:RangeValidator to change the minimum and maximum value programmatically. Unfortunately I am seeing a console error message stating:

'Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The value '' of the MaximumValue property of 'rvDateFrom' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.

My code can be seen below. The calendar is contained in the EditItemTemplate of a ListView, which is contained in an UpdatePanel.

```
<ewc:CalendarPopup ID="cpDateFrom" runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Bind("DateFrom")%>' CssClass="date"></ewc:CalendarPopup>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rvDateFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cpDateFrom" Type="Date" ErrorMessage="Invalid"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

The code behind is as follows:

```
Private Sub lvRangeValidatorTest_ItemEditing(sender As Object, e As ListViewEditEventArgs) Handles lvRangeValidator.ItemEditing
    lvRangeValidator.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    DataBind()

    Dim rvDateFrom As RangeValidator = CType(lvRangeValidatorTest.Items(e.NewEditIndex).FindControl("rvDateFrom"), RangeValidator
    rvDateFrom.MinimumValue = "01/01/1900"
    rvDateFrom.MaximumValue = "01/01/2020"
End Sub
```

The RangeValidator is found, as intentionally entering the incorrect name throws an instance of an object error, but it does not seem to actually update the RangeValidator. Thus leaving the minimum and maximum values blank.

Thoughts?

Many thanks.

Comment: As mentioned in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.maximumvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), the date should be specified in a format such as YYYY/MM/DD. You could use: `rvDateFrom.MinimumValue = "1900/01/01"`. An answer to the post [Date format in RangeValidator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332600/date-format-in-rangevalidator) gives the same information.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but the error is showing a blank value cannot be converted to type date.

I've used that date format in other areas on the application with no issue. I only have issues when using the EditItemTemplate.

Comment: The culture is specified within the web application so I do not need to use a culture-neutral date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and unsuccessfully trying to use the ItemDataBound event, I successfully used the DataBound event.

```
lvRangeValidatorTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvRangeValidatorTest.DataBound
   If lvRangeValidatorTest.EditItem IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim rvDateFrom As RangeValidator = CType(lvRangeValidator.EditItem.FindControl("rvDateFrom"), RangeValidator)
      rvDateFrom.MinimumValue = "01/01/1900"
      rvDateFrom.MaximumValue = "01/01/2020"
   End If
End Sub
```